# Boolean combinations

Tags: combinatorics

Given all the possible combinations of a $n$-bit binary word as $2^n$, I need a formula to calculate the number of combinations with $m$ bits ($m<=n$) exactly $1$ (or $0$). For example say I had a $7$-bit word and wanted to now how many combinations there were with any $5$-bit being $1$ (or $0$)?

Answer (score 2):

Given that this is a binary choice, there is a formula exactly for that kind of thing:

$${n\choose{m}} =\frac{n!}{m!(n-m)!}$$

E.g with $n=7$ and $m=5$ you get:

$${7\choose5}=\frac{7!}{5!2!}=21$$